# JQuery function suddenly stopped working with error converting Javascript argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

about a year ago I wrote a JQuery/Javascript script which makes an ajax call to a PHP page to change a user password, and it has been working wonderfully ever since. Earlier today I started getting complaints that the ajax call is no longer working. When I go to submit the password change form I get the following error:

> Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]
>   http://www.site.com/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
>   Line 124

Even though this error occurs, the user's password is changed, and the ouput from the PHP is exactly as it should be... a properly formatted json string:

```
{"Authenticated":{"0":"false"},"MessageString":{"0":"Your User Password Was Changed Successfully."},"PasswordChanged":{"0":"true"}}
```

None of the files associated with this project have been changed in several months, and this form gets used at least a few times a day, so I'm not sure why it suddenly stopped working.

Here is the script I am running, and I am running it with JQuery 1.4.4:

```
function makePasswordRequest() {
    email = jQuery("#email").val();
    currentPassword = jQuery("#currentPassword").val();
    newPassword = jQuery("#newPassword").val();
    newPasswordRetype = jQuery("#newPasswordRetype").val();
    jQuery.post("../changeUserPassword.php", { 
            email: email, 
            currentPassword: currentPassword, 
            newPassword: newPassword, 
            newPasswordRetype: newPasswordRetype 
        },
         function(data){
           if(data.PasswordChanged[0] == true || data.PasswordChanged[0] == "true"){
                jQuery("#notificationArea").removeClass("failure");
                jQuery("#notificationArea").addClass("success");
           }
           else{
                jQuery("#notificationArea").removeClass("success");
                jQuery("#notificationArea").addClass("failure");
           }
           jQuery("#notificationArea").html(data.MessageString);
         }, "json");
};
function resetPasswordRequest() {
    email = jQuery("#email2").val();
    jQuery.post("../resetUserPassword.php", { 
            email: email,  
        },
         function(data){
           if(data.PasswordChanged[0] == true || data.PasswordChanged[0] == "true"){
                jQuery("#notificationArea2").removeClass("failure");
                jQuery("#notificationArea2").addClass("success");
           }
           else{
                jQuery("#notificationArea2").removeClass("success");
                jQuery("#notificationArea2").addClass("failure");
           }
           jQuery("#notificationArea2").html(data.MessageString);
         }, "json");
};
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#passwordChangeForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        makePasswordRequest();
    });
    jQuery("#passwordResetForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        resetPasswordRequest();
    });
});
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, especially since this has been working well for the last year. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you update to 1.7 before testing?

Comment: During development we used JQuery 1.4.4, and this site is still running 1.4.4. Nothing in the site should have changed.

Comment: Did the ajax domain change?  Edit:  Im wondering if it has to do with the new released FF13?

Comment: Things don't break when nothing changes. Something must have changed. Find that and you can fix it.

Comment: No. As far as I can tell, nothing on this project has changed in quite some time.

Comment: It'd help if you could use an un-minified version of jQuery. That would make it easier to trace back through the stack and find out exactly where in your code the error is happening.

Comment: More than likely the only thing that has changed is the firefox version. I don't see anything that would cause an error.

Comment: you can use developer tools to see the call stack. maybe you'll get a clue for the place where the error starts.
also, can you try it in an older browser?

Comment: This error occurs in every browser I have tested, and accoring to firebug originates in the JQuery core on line 124. I am at a total loss for what could be causing the problem.

Comment: instead of expecting the console to give the OP the exact problem, try putting alerts in to see how far it gets before it fails...

Comment: Just because it points to the core, doesn't mean the root of the problem is in the core. Include the non-minified version of jQuery 1.4.4 and you'll get a more realistic line number that we can then match up to a method in your code. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js

Comment: firebug has a stack tab, with that you can trace from where its called the jquery function thats causing the error. that way you can pinpoint the argument(most likely) its causing jquery to explode.
if you provide a jsfiddle with the html we can check it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this would be a problem, but when you're setting the inner HTML of the one element with:

```
jQuery("#notificationArea").html(data.MessageString);
```

data.MessageString is {"0":"Your User Password Was Changed Successfully."}, so I wonder if that could be a problem? Wouldn't you want data.MessageString[0]?

Comment: Interesting. With that code, it shouldn't error, but it would be appending the string `"[object Object]"` rather than the actual message. This suggests that the OP code may not be the actual code.

Comment: would jquery know to convert the object to a string though? it wouldn't fail/complain? i can't test that right now, but yeah it if it knew to convert it, then it wouldn't fail, just show that string

Comment: I'm not sure what has changed in the universe, but that solved my problem. This worked for a year before now without the [0], but for some reason now it barfs if it's not there. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: yeah that's what's weird - why would it work before? if you were using [0] on the other attributes (like data.PasswordChanged), I would think you'd need it everywhere for your setup. either way, glad this fixed it!

Comment: That is really odd. I can't explain it. I can definitely get it to work without the `[0]` though. http://jsfiddle.net/xrdfH/

Comment: you can't compare javascript to jquery. you used javascript .innerHTML, whereas jquery wraps that with .html() and does much more than just set .innerHTML. look at: http://jsfiddle.net/xrdfH/1/ (it fails)

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the problem lies in jquery not detecting it's JSON and not converting JSON properly. Try sending the proper headers right before the output.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

What must have changed is your server's config. Which doesn't really depend on you

Comment: He has `, "json"` in his post, jquery will assume that it is json regardless of content-type header.

Comment: I spent several hours trying to solve the same problem (but with $.ajax) and the headers were the sollution. It's just some thing to try, not a definite sollution :)

Comment: if you look at the jQuery docs, jQuery first looks at the MIME type in the response headers and attempts to convert the response to that. but since they specified "json", that overrides the header. i think that's why you can always return plain text from the server, but setting the dataType allows for correct conversion. not sure how accurate that is though. but that's why a change on the server for the return MIME type wouldn't affect this situation - they set it to expect "json"